# Getting Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lowagie/text/Document

Tags: itext

I am using java 1.4 . I tried itext library of versions 1.4,1.4.8 and 2.1.7. I have created java project and put the code in main function then it's working fine but when I put the code in web application and create an ear and after deploying ear on server. I am getting above error. Itext is also available in classpath.

Comment: Please check if you have multiple versions of iText on your classpath. Finding multiple classes with the same FQDN will cause a `NoClassDefFoundError`, even though it would be better if it were named a `MultipleClassDefsFoundError`.

Comment: I have checked that.  I don't have multiple versions of jar in classpath. Is there any chance that server has different classpath.

Comment: Please explain why you are using Java 1.4.

Comment: One reason for using java 1.4 could be it is commercial software in a customer's old environment. If so, take a look at http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse: We are having a portal which is on Java 1.4. No plans for upgradation.

Comment: My sympathies. Check the classpath on your server. Chances are that it is different.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse: I checked that as well. No luck in that.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I don't know anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. We have a project and have ear and war project as well. I put the dependency in  project.xml of all. I made 3 entries for dependency. Finally It worked for me.  :)